# Create an empty object at deep path with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

I need to create an empty object at a deep path but only if it is not exist and return a reference to that object.

This can be accomplished by using `_.has`, `_.set` and then `_.get`

```
let path = 'some.deep.path';

if (!_.has(object, path)) {
    _.set(object, path, {});
}

let descendant = _.get(object, path);
```

What I would like instead, is to avoid repeating the `object`, `path` (or introducing the `path` variable to avoid repeating the `path` value)

I wonder if there's a way to do that without extra function/library.

---

#### List of lodash methods that accept or deal with a path. Alphabetically

This includes methods that deal with arrays/collections and accept the `_.property` iteratee/predicate shorthand, i.e. when a string is provided as an argument, it is passed over to the `_.property` method that creates a function which returns the value at path of a given object (that was given by the main function, e.g. `_.map`).

**Array**

- *v4.0.0* [_.differenceBy](https://lodash.com/docs#differenceBy)(array, [values], [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v3.0.0* [_.dropRightWhile](https://lodash.com/docs#dropRightWhile)(array, [predicate=_.identity])
- *v3.0.0* [_.dropWhile](https://lodash.com/docs#dropWhile)(array, [predicate=_.identity])
- *v1.1.0* [_.findIndex](https://lodash.com/docs#findIndex)(array, [predicate=_.identity], [fromIndex=0])
- *v2.0.0* [_.findLastIndex](https://lodash.com/docs#findLastIndex)(array, [predicate=_.identity], [fromIndex=array.length-1])
- *v4.0.0* [_.intersectionBy](https://lodash.com/docs#intersectionBy)([arrays], [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v4.0.0* [_.sortedIndexBy](https://lodash.com/docs#sortedIndexBy)(array, value, [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v4.0.0* [_.sortedLastIndexBy](https://lodash.com/docs#sortedLastIndexBy)(array, value, [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v3.0.0* [_.takeRightWhile](https://lodash.com/docs#takeRightWhile)(array, [predicate=_.identity])
- *v3.0.0* [_.takeWhile](https://lodash.com/docs#takeWhile)(array, [predicate=_.identity])
- *v4.0.0* [_.unionBy](https://lodash.com/docs#unionBy)([arrays], [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v4.0.0* [_.uniqBy](https://lodash.com/docs#uniqBy)(array, [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v4.0.0* [_.xorBy](https://lodash.com/docs#unionBy)([arrays], [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v4.1.0* [_.zipObjectDeep](https://lodash.com/docs#zipObjectDeep)([props=[]],  [values=[]])

**Collection**

- *v0.5.0* [_.countBy](https://lodash.com/docs#countBy)(collection, [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v0.1.0* [_.every](https://lodash.com/docs#every)(collection, [predicate=_.identity])
- *v0.1.0* [_.filter](https://lodash.com/docs#filter)(collection, [predicate=_.identity])
- *v0.1.0* [_.find](https://lodash.com/docs#find)(collection, [predicate=_.identity])
- *v0.1.0* [_.groupBy](https://lodash.com/docs#groupBy)(collection, [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v4.0.0* [_.invokeMap](https://lodash.com/docs#invokeMap)(collection, path, [args])
- *v0.1.0* [_.map](https://lodash.com/docs#map)(collection, [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v3.0.0* [_.partition](https://lodash.com/docs#partition)(collection, [predicate=_.identity])
- *v0.1.0* [_.reject](https://lodash.com/docs#reject)(collection, [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v0.1.0* [_.some](https://lodash.com/docs#some)(collection, [iteratee=_.identity])

**Math**

- *v4.0.0* [_.maxBy](https://lodash.com/docs#maxBy)(array, [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v4.7.0* [_.meanBy](https://lodash.com/docs#meanBy)(array, [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v4.0.0* [_.minBy](https://lodash.com/docs#minBy)(array, [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v4.0.0* [_.sumBy](https://lodash.com/docs#sumBy)(array, [iteratee=_.identity])

**Object**

- *v1.0.0* [_.at](https://lodash.com/docs#at)(object, [paths])
- *v1.1.0* [_.findKey](https://lodash.com/docs#findKey)(object, [predicate=_.identity])
- *v2.0.0* [_.findLastKey](https://lodash.com/docs#findLastKey)(object, [predicate=_.identity])
- *v3.7.0* [_.get](https://lodash.com/docs#get)(object, path, [defaultValue])
- *v0.1.0* [_.has](https://lodash.com/docs#has)(object, path)
- *v4.0.0* [_.hasIn](https://lodash.com/docs#hasIn)(object, path)
- *v4.0.0* [_.invoke](https://lodash.com/docs#invoke)(object, path, [args])
- *v2.4.0* [_.mapValues](https://lodash.com/docs#mapValues)(object, [iteratee=_.identity])
- *v0.1.0* [_.omit](https://lodash.com/docs#omit)(object, [paths])
- *v0.1.0* [_.pick](https://lodash.com/docs#pick)(object, [paths])
- *v0.1.0* [_.result](https://lodash.com/docs#result)(object, path, [defaultValue])
- *v3.7.0* [_.set](https://lodash.com/docs#set)(object, path, value)
- *v4.0.0* [_.setWith](https://lodash.com/docs#setWith)(object, path, value, [customizer])
- *v4.0.0* [_.unset](https://lodash.com/docs#unset)(object, path)
- *v4.6.0* [_.update](https://lodash.com/docs#update)(object, path, updater)
- *v4.6.0* [_.updateWith](https://lodash.com/docs#updateWith)(object, path, updater, [customizer])

**Util**

- *v4.0.0* [_.iteratee](https://lodash.com/docs#iteratee)([func=_.identity])
- *v3.2.0* [_.matchesProperty](https://lodash.com/docs#matchesProperty)(path, srcValue)
- *v3.7.0* [_.method](https://lodash.com/docs#method)(path, [args])
- *v3.7.0* [_.methodOf](https://lodash.com/docs#methodOf)(object, [args])
- *v2.4.0* [_.property](https://lodash.com/docs#property)(path)
- *v3.0.0* [_.propertyOf](https://lodash.com/docs#propertyOf)(object)
- *v4.0.0* [_.toPath](https://lodash.com/docs#toPath)(value)

**Seq**

Chained methods, i.e. methods that are called in a **seq**uence, e.g.:

```
_(value).chained().method().value();
```

- *v1.0.0* [_.prototype.at](https://lodash.com/docs#prototype-at)([paths])

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a `_.deepDefault` method in an extra [lodash-deep](https://github.com/marklagendijk/lodash-deep/tree/1.6.0#_deepdefaultcollection-propertypath-defaultvalue) library that checks if the value at the `propertyPath` resolves to `undefined`, and sets it to `defaultValue` if this is the case:

```
var descendant = _.deepDefault(object, 'some.deep.path', {});
```

That library is not updated anymore because Lodash now supports most of the functionality natively so here's an implementation as a lodash mixin function:

```
function getOrSetDefault(object, path, defaultValue) {
    const descendant = _.get(object, path);
    if (descendant === undefined) {
        _.set(object, path, defaultValue);
    }
    return descendant;
}

_.mixin({ getOrSetDefault });

const a = _.getOrSetDefault(object, 'some.deep.path', 42);
const b = _.getOrSetDefault(object, 'some.other.deep.path', {});
b.c = 42;
```

With the new optional chaining operator and a logical nullish assignment there would be no need to use lodash for this particular case (if it is acceptable to populate/define `some.deep.path` with a default value), e.g.:

```
some?.deep?.path ??= {}
const { foo } = some.deep.path
```

Unfortunately optional chaining assignments are not available yet.
See https://stackoverflow.com/a/58882121/1949503

There would be just one drawback in that there'll be a need to repeat property accessors (`some.deep.path`) to retrieve the value. However in this case we will have autocompletion using Typescript/JSDoc unlike in lodash funcions' path argument (either string or array)

If there's only a need to get value at path the vanilla `try/catch` could be sufficient:

```
let foo: Foo;
try {
  foo = some.deep.path.foo
} catch {}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can avoid the `_.has` with this:

```
var path = 'some.deep.path',
descendant = _.get(object, path);
if (!descendant) {
    descendant = {};
    _.set(object, path, descendant);
}
```

Thus traversing the path only 2 times, instead of 3.

Comment: doesn't work if path contains numeric keys: var path = 'some.22.11'

Answer (score 1):

Now you can use _.setWith

```
setWith({}, "some.deep.path", value, Object);
```

returning

```
{some:{deep:{path:4}}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can go straight to the point in one line with

```js
const object = _.set({}, 'some.deep.path', {value: 'foo'})
```

Or, if you already have an object that you want to update

```
const obj = {some: {deep: {path: {barbecue: ''}}}}
const path = 'some.deep.path'

_.set(obj, path, {..._.get(obj, path, {}), foo: 'bar'})
// => {some: {deep: {path: {barbecue: '', foo: 'bar' }}}}
```

Comment: That would overwrite whole `some.deep.path` object instead of adding/changing the `value` 

(imagine that `some.deep.path` already contains `{ value: 'bar', otherValue: 'egg' }`

Comment: `_.set(obj, path, _.get(obj, path, {}));` is a good one  even if it requires referencing `obj` and `path` twice. The task was to obtain a reference to an object at path and create that object at path if it doesn't exist. `_.set` returns the `obj` instead of `obj.some.deep.path.barbecue` ;)

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
function getDefault(obj, path, defaultValue) {
  _.update(obj, path, d => d ? d : {})
  return _.get(obj, path);
}
```

If the path doesn't exist it will be created, otherwise it's not changed.
Still not sure of a way to avoid the `get` though..