# Only execute code if element exists, but with no dublicate if statement in Javascript

Tags: javascript, if-statement

I was wondering if you could make this:

```
if(document.getElementsByClassName("whatever")[0]) {
    document.getElementsByClassName("whatever")[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

*(It checkes if the element exists, and then only excicutes the code if it is true)*

But without the if statment, because it doesn't look like a good practise to dublicate the `document.getElementsByClassName("whatever")[0]`, and it makes it more anoying when having to do alot of bug testing with the document.getElementsByClassName.

Comment: You can save off the results of `document.getElementsByClassName("whatever")` into a variable and then check it as many times as you want without having to re-look through the DOM

Comment: Do you need it to work for all elements with the specified classNames or just first one?

Comment: A good chance to read up [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

Comment: Nice one @jarmod :)

Comment: @Dominik Just realized optional chaining is [not usable in the assignment case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878948/optional-chaining-on-the-left-side-in-javascript), sadly.

Answer (score 1):

Simply set it to a variable, check if anything was found, and use that variable to modify it's display:

```
let whatever = document.getElementsByClassName("whatever");
if(whatever.length  > 0) {
    whatever[0].style.display = "none";
}
```

Comment: Subtle bug potential if the index was not zero.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to only hide the first element with a specific className, you can define a method like this:

```
function hideIfExists(className){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    if(elements.length  > 0){
      elements[0].style.display = 'none';
    }
   
}
```

Then use it like this:

```
hideIfExists('hello')
hideIfExists('someOtherClass')
...
```

If you need it to hide all elements, your method might look like this

```
function hideIfExists(className){
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName(className);
    for (let item of elements) {
      item.style.display = 'none';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In my personal opinion, this is the simplest and still most elegant way to avoid the duplicate code, but also avoid extra code lines, so to keep it well readable:

```
if(elem = document.getElementsByClassName("whatever")[0]) {
    elem.style.display = "none";
}
```

Your editor might give you a warning about an assignment in a conditional expression. This seems totally okay to me, but you can avoid it by extra parens around the assignment. However, I think this reduces readability and should therefore better not be done.

Comment: Thanks, this is much cleaner :)

Answer (score 0):

You could destructure the element and assign only if `element` is truthy.

```js
const [element] = document.getElementsByClassName("whatever");

if (element) element.style.display = "none";
```

```html
<div class="whatever">1</div>
<div class="whatever">2</div>
<div class="whatever">3</div>
```