# Optional chaining with assignment

Tags: javascript, object, properties

ES16+ offers a nice shorthand `obj.someMethod?.()` to call someMethod if exists on calling object.

Beeing spoiled with this coding sugar, I would also like to assign a value to property if exists, something like `obj?.someProp = 42` (which leads to invalid left-hand assignment).

I would like to do it with any object (mostly dataset of HTMLElements). Any idea how to shorten this?

```js
if(obj?.hasOwnProperty("someProp")) obj.someProp = 42
```

Comment: The or `||` operator might come in handy here, 

Depends on where you're using the value, for example: 

`let var = obj.someProp || 42`

var will evaluate to 42 if `obj.someProp` is null or undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### There is not currently any syntactical sugar for this using Javascript

It was raised in the [tc39 proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining) that brought us [optional chaining](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining) under the discussion [should we include "optional property assignment" `a?.b = c`](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining/issues/18), but ultimately [not supported](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-optional-chaining#not-supported).

However, this is supported by **CoffeeScript's** [**existential operator**](https://coffeescript.org/#existential-operator) which given the [following example](https://coffeescript.org/#try:el%20%3D%20document.getElementById(%22a%22)%0A%0Ael%3F.href%20%3D%20%22b%22):

```js
el?.href = "b"
```

CoffeeScript will compile into the following output:

```js
if (el != null) {
  el.href = "b";
}
```

**Related**: [Optional chaining on the left side in Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58878948/1366033)

Answer (score 2):

well, you can do something like:

```
obj && (obj.someProp = 42)
```

But this will not create the `obj` for you..

However, even though its not asked, why not just simply destructure though?

```
obj = {...(obj || {}), someProp: 42}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [logical nullish assignment operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment). It won't help you with `obj` being undefined though:

```
if (obj) obj.someProp ??= 42;
```

Comment: Interesting, but it does the exact opposite: assigns the value to `someProp` only if it is nullish (i.e. doesn't exist) in `obj`.

Answer (score 0):

I also find Proxy to be useful in some cases:

```
    const Accessor = obj => new Proxy(obj, {
        get: (o, prop) => o[prop],
        set: (o, prop, val) => prop in o ? (o[prop]=val) : val
    });

    const obj = { a: 20 };
    const accObj = Accessor(obj);
    accObj.a = 24; // obj.a = accObj.a = 24
    occObj.b = 24; // no effect
```