# What are alternative methods for left side optional chaining in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, optional-chaining

Being that in Javascript optional chaining on the left side of an assignment is not possible, as noted in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58878948/optional-chaining-on-the-left-side-in-javascript) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58882121/9530790), what are some possible alternative methods to achieve this?

```
customer.details?.car = { make: 'Toyta' }
```

1. I know you can do that with an `if`

   ```
   if (customer.details) {
       customer.details.car = { make: 'Toyota' };
   } else {
       customer.details = { car: { make: 'Toyota' } };
   }
   ```
2. I tried with Logical OR || but I'm not sure it's possible and the below is not correct

   ```
   customer.(details || {}).car = { make: 'Toyota' };
   ```
3. Ternary with spread works (with [help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72606578/9530790) from @garrettmills)

   ```
   customer.details = customer.details 
       ? { ...customer.details, car: { make: 'Toyota' } }
       : { details: { car: { make: 'Toyota' } } };
   ```

Are there any other methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for [logical nullish assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_nullish_assignment), the short form of `x = x ?? y`:

```
(customer.details ??= {}).car = { make: 'Toyota' };
```

It also works nice with chaining, e.g.

```
((customer.details ??= {}).car ??= {}).make = 'Toyota';
```

Comment: Okay, TIL. That's just cool.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer:

```js
customer.details = {
    ...(customer.details || {}),
    car: { make: 'toyota' },
}
```

since it implies that you are "overlaying" details with a new property.

It's worth noting that your example (3) doesn't seem to work quite right. If the customer already has a details field, then the entire customer record will be replaced with `{ details: { car: ... } }`.

Comment: I edited my question to fix example 3, thank you.